# How to keep track of focused elements in a form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I'm new to vuejs and I'm wondering what would be the best way to keep track of the latest focused input/textarea in a form in order to programatically modify their values from the parent component.

**Example**

```
Form
  Input1
  Input2 -> focused
  Textarea
Button (onclick -> appends "hello" to the focused input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

You can create a data property that tracks the currently focused/last focused `input` element. In the below example this is called **current_focus**.

To do this you **could** use the `focus` event - but because `focus` doesn't bubble you would have to apply it to each individual `input` element manually.

It is easier to provide a `focusin` event handler to the parent. This event, unlike `focus`, bubbles up the DOM from any child to its parent. This allows you to utilize an event delegation pattern.

Event Delegation means that you apply one handler to a parent for an event, then do something depending on the source of the event. This means when we receive a `focusin` event, we can simply check if the focused element is an `input` element, then update our data property ( **current_focus** )

---

### Code Sandbox Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-handler-vzip0

---

### Code Example:

**FocusDemo.js**

```
<template>
  <div v-on:focusin="updateFocus">
    <input name="one">
    <br>
    <input name="two">
    <br>
    <input name="three">
    <br>
    <button @click="handleClick">Add Text To Focused</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FocusDemo",
  data: function() {
    return {
      current_focus: undefined
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateFocus: function(e) {
      let element = e.target;
      if (element.matches("input")) {
        this.current_focus = element;
      }
    },
    handleClick: function(e) {
      if (this.current_focus) {
        this.current_focus.value = "Button was clicked!";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```